# Interrupted statement in java lambda

Tags: java, lambda, collections, functional-programming, java-stream

I have this code

```
    Integer[] i = {1,3,4,6,7,43,2,1};
    //create a predicate
    Predicate<Integer> ini = value -> value > 10;;
    //display-filter-and print the values in the collection
    List<Integer> sss =Stream.of(i).peek(e -> System.out.println(e)).filter(ini).
            peek(value -> System.out.println("After filter " + value)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    //display the filtered list
    System.out.println(sss);
```

And I'm getting this result

```
1
3
4
6
7
43
After filter 43
2
1 
[43]
```

My question is why I'm getting the filter message in between in the middle of the peek statement? I tried this in different IDEs but I'm getting the same results.

Comment: You don’t get the message “in the middle of the peek statement” as there is no “peek statement”. There’s a single stream operation and you’re seeing how the stream operation works, which is precisely what `peek` is meant for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you surprised?

You have two `peek()` method calls. The first one is before the filter and the second after the filter.

Your stream pipeline consumes one element at a time (and that takes place as a result of executing the terminal operation `collect()`).

Consuming an element of your stream involves applying the first `peek()`, which prints the element, followed by applying the filter.

Only if the element passes the filter, the second `peek()` is applied, and prints "After filter ..".

The only element that passes the filter is 43, which results in

```
43
After filter 43
```

being printed when it is consumed.

Only later the remaining elements are consumed, and printed when the first `peek` is applied on them.